# Angular HttpClient multiple calls

Tags: typescript, observable, angular5

I found a disturbing fact in my Angular 5 App.

This little call in my service:

```
interface U{
  name:string;
}
...

constructor(private http : *Http*, private httpC:HttpClient) // Http is deprecated - its a compare test

...
ping() //Test Debug func
  {
    let o:Observable<U> = this.httpC.get<U>(this.url + "user/1");

    o.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("SUBSCRIBE1: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      return resp;
    },
    this.handleError);

    o.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("SUBSCRIBE2: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      return resp;
    },
    this.handleError);

    o.toPromise().then(resp => {
      console.log("PROMISE: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      return resp;
    });
  }
```

Now on ping() call **Angular/Browser is actually calling three times** "url/user/1"
Once for each listener (2 subscribes, 1 promise)

Is that used to be like this?

My understanding of an Observer is that I can add multiple "Listeners" which are waiting for an action. NOT trigger the action.

Whats wrong here? Do I have some broken setup after update or something?

**Some clearence or an example how to do something like this right** would be realy great! 
Thanks for any input.

**EDIT:** I extend the experiment with a further call with deprecated HTTP client which is doing the same. So it seems to be by design. Just dont understand how to catch multiple times WITHOUT calling multiple times.

```
 ping() //Test Debug func
  {
    let o:Observable<U> = this.httpC.get<U>(this.url + "user/1");

    o.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("SUBSCRIBE1: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      console.log(resp);
      //this.currentUser = resp;
      return resp;
    },
    this.handleError);

    o.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("SUBSCRIBE2: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      console.log(resp);
      //this.currentUser = resp;
      return resp;
    },
    this.handleError);

    o.toPromise().then(resp => {
      console.log("PROMISE1: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      console.log(resp);
      //this.currentUser = resp;
      return resp;
    });

    o.toPromise().then(resp => {
      console.log("PROMISE2: Init:get:user:U: " + resp.name);
      console.log(resp);
      //this.currentUser = resp;
      return resp;
    });


    let call:string = this.url + "user/1";
    return this.http.get(call)
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp => {
          console.log("OLD HTTP PROMISE 1 " + resp);

          return resp;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .then(resp => {
          console.log("OLD HTTP PROMISE 2 " + resp);

          return resp;
        });
  }
```

And this is what Chrome-Network shows after one ping call:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us that they trigger a request or are they just handling 1 response 3 times?

Comment: I can send you the screenshot of the Chrom-Network overview....

Comment: I think your call and subscriptions are not supposed to be in the same function. You would normally have the subscriber in a component and the request being made from a service.

Comment: Yes, thats the usual use-case. But I just understand that anyway. And if it works properly after a return of the Promise/Observable it would confuse me even more :)

Comment: OK... now Iam completly out: chaining the Promises inside method returns, It is called only one time and catched multiple times (once per method) ... explaination? PLEASE! :D

Comment: ... BUT method chain with Observer returns still trigger the multiple calls

Comment: ...ALSO interesting fact: Using 'HttpClient' calls and listening only '.toPromise()' does NOT trigger any Angular Interceptors.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding of an Observer is that I can add multiple "Listeners" which are waiting for an action. NOT trigger the action.

I think you are confusing `subscribe()` with a promise's `then()`. But Unlike with promises, where subsequent calls to `then` will return exactly the same result, calling `subscribe()` on a ''cold'' observable will not subscribe to the "same" result but will actually create a new "producer" with each `subscribe()` call and each "producer" will generate ("produce") a new distinct result. For a good explanation on hot and cold observables consider reading [this](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) great article by Ben Lesh.

> Whats wrong here? Do I have some broken setup after update or something?

What I described above is what is also happening in your example with the `HttpClient`'s `get()`: It creates a cold observable whose producer (i.e. the request) will be recreated (re-executed) on every call.

You can make the client's "cold" http-request observable "hot" though, i.e. sharing the objservable's source/sequence, using rxJS `share()` – or in your case preferably `shareReplay`, which [replays values](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html).